# Different representation of class 'bytes' in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have two variables of the class `bytes` in python3.

```
print(string1) --> b'2900BCE03604093C000080'
print(bytes.fromhex(string1.decode('utf8'))) --> b')\x00\xbc\xe06\x04\t<\x00\x00\x80'

print(type(string1)) --> <class 'bytes'>
print(type(bytes.fromhex(string1.decode('utf8')))) --> <class 'bytes'>
```

The strange values in the second output are there because of ascii interpretation of some hex-values.

My Question is how to convert the `string1` more easily to the output of the second line. Is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe this is a duplication but I was confused by the other answer. A 'normal' string has been used as input in the other discussion and here the author uses a b'..' style 'string'. Please note, I am confused and may not use the proper wording. Corrections regarding this welcom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`binascii.a2b_hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex) function to get the hexadecimal representation of the binary data:

```
In [5]: binascii.a2b_hex(s)
Out[5]: b')\x00\xbc\xe06\x04\t<\x00\x00\x80'
```